# Aria roles and inner divs

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I am updating an old site to make it more accessible.

On the site there are a number of places which have a structure on the lines of:

```
<div class="topbar">
    <div class="inner">
        Content here ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Should the `role="banner"` be on the `.topbar` div or the `.inner` div? Should I be adding anything to the other div?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going through an old site to make it more accessible then updating to HTML5 would be preferable.

As such I would use the [`<header>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header) element instead of `role="banner"`.

```
<header class="topbar">
    <div class="inner">
        Content here ...
    </div>
</header>
```

This would have exactly the same semantics as `role="banner"` but without the need for WAI-ARIA and with better support for things like navigating by regions.

Repeat this process throughout the site using semantically correct elements instead of `<div>`s and you will find you need very little WAI-ARIA.

Comment: So basically you're saying that the outer div should be updated for accessibility and the inner div doesn't need to be changed?

Comment: Exactly, that is correct, but you should use a `<header>` element as stated.

Comment: I understand that, but my question was generic and applies to many areas that are not headers - the `role="banner"` in my post was just an example of one specific place, I was really trying to understand whether it's better for a screen reader to have the role on the div (or change the div to a header/main/section/aside etc) closest to the content, or on the outermost wrapper.

Comment: **Nearly always the outermost wrapper.** You have to bear in mind that `<div>`s have no semantic meaning so they get ignored by Assistive Devices. It would still work if you put it on the `.inner` div as the `topbar` div has no meaning on its own. But is better on the outer div just for clarity reasons and so the accessibility tree is neater. Obviously if you are changing it to a header/main etc. those should be top level elements anyway so at that point go outer rather than inner. Outermost without interfering with another landmark is the best practice.

Comment: Thanks - If you would like to edit your answer to state that part as well, I will be happy to accept it as the answer.